# MYSQL: Insert a timestamp from a variable to a table

Tags: mysql, ruby, sql-insert

I have an INSERT query in ruby and I'm passing parameters from another table. One of the parameters is a timestamp value, for example: 2015-11-22 12:57:06 +0000 which is stored in a variable name created_at (of type Time)

```
   insert into my_tbl set
          name = '#{name}',
          created_at = #{created_at}
```

and I'm always getting errors while trying to insert it.
I've tried to convert it to string, and to use str_to_date function, but the problem is that I have a timestamp value.

How can I insert the value to the table?

Comment: Are you using rails ? If so, you could use a parametrised query instead `MyModel.connection.execute("update my_tbl set name = ?, created_at = ?", name, created_at) `

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use rails, so I need to figure out how to make this happen without it

Comment: what database adapter do you use ?

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes I used your suggestion + the function str_to_date and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO my_tbl (name, created_at)
  VALUES (name, created_at.to_s.split(' +').first)
```

Answer (score 0):

Format the input in mysql from chat and from ruby program insert and format in this chat with the sale format

Update:
In mysql :

Select to_date('"+varchar+"','dd/mm/yyyy'......

In Ruby:
Varchar='01/12/2015"

Of course with format

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean. Can you explain more?